# google.maps is defined but does not work

Tags: javascript, google-maps

After loading the Maps API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp), I just test the following basic map init, which fails. This is just copy-paste from Map's tutorial.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

In Chrome dev tools I get the error : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

If I type in the console :

> google
>   -> Object {loader: Object, load: function, T: function.....
>
> google.maps
>   -> Object {modules: Object, **__gjsload__**: function, Load: function}
>
> google.maps.LatLng
>   -> undefined
>
> google.maps.Map
>   -> undefined
>
> google.maps.event
>   -> undefined

The div id="map-canvas" exists, it has a width, a height and a blue border and I can see an empty blue rectangle in my page.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your API Key embedded in the API Link from Google Maps? Also is this code within the document.ready function?

Comment: From what I could read, the API key is not mandatory but "should" be included (am I wrong?) - I have to use requireJS in the project, to make sure everything is loaded before launch. This code is in a "require" statement so everything should be loaded

Comment: The API key is mandatory, the MAP won't load without it. You can get it [by the developers console from google](https://console.developers.google.com), it's free. At least that was the case for me

Comment: OK I'll try that, thanks. the tutorial page states " If your application's Maps API usage exceeds the Usage Limits, you must load the Maps API using an API key in order to purchase additional quota". I understand the key is not mandatory just to init a map.

Comment: @KhorneHoly the API key is NOT mandatory. Also the initialize function doesn't have to be wrapped inside document.ready; it's covered by the window load event listener

Comment: The Docu quotes "All Maps API applications* should load the Maps API using an API key". Well, it says it should, but only `buisness APIs musn't do it`. I guess that a bit of misscomunication. Maybe it'll work :) Also the limit lays to 25k loads straight for 3 months, so there shouldn't be a big risk to get charged

Comment: @duncan Yeah, but i had for me and other cases on SO that the Map wasn't loaded until the API Key. But that with the load event is my mistake, forgot about that

Comment: It definitely works without it, otherwise it would say 'must load' not 'should load'. You may run into issues if you exceed usage limits, but otherwise you'll be fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to include this link on the head tag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

I saw your code the same on the google map sample. If you want, refer to this site.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: This works. For some reason, RequireJS loads like "part of" the API, making the google.maps object defined, but not google.maps.LatLng or other methods inside. Calling the API the old way (from the HTML)  did the trick. Now I have to make it work with RequireJS... thanks lad

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you have tried with code, can you please note the below [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/XyW9x/) code.

If you have further query or comments, then please mention them, and edit the jsfiddle.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Regards D.

Comment: Thanks Devang. It looks like the problem came from the API inclusion with RequireJS.